# What numerical method can be recommended to solve an exponential system of equations with two unknowns?

Tags: numerical-methods, exponential-function, systems-of-equations, maple

Everytime I have to work with chemical kinetics, I end up with having to deal with a system of two equations involving the unknowns being on the exponents as follows:

Let's say:

$$\cases{4^x+7^y=53\\
3^x+8^y=67}$$

Typically when I have a system of linear equations such as

$$\cases{ax+by=c\\
a_1x+b_1y=c_1}$$

I could use Gauss Jordan or any of the methods involving matrices or whatsoever.

However when the unknowns appear in the exponential makes it unable to solve with regular methods covered in algebra.

Therefore what would be the recommended numerical method to solve this with a good degree of accuracy to the exact answer?.

The kind of method which I'm looking for is something which doesn't involve much iterations and can be easier to apply each time such situation event (two unknowns as in this context) arises.

I'll appreciate that an answer could use my example and be the most detailed as possible.

**Can maple be used on this using Newton Raphson?**

Since I use maple, my intention is that a suggested answer could indicate a short sequence or algorithm which can be input in maple to solve this kind of situations other than using the command solve.

Comment: Some times, you can check and you are lucky and there is an integer solution. Like $4 + 49 = 53$ and $3 + 64 = 67$. If not, then I strongly suspect that this is **difficult**.

Comment: I am surprised that such equations appear in chemical kinetics. Usually, the solution can only be determined numerically.

Comment: @Peter They do, when establishing the order of a reaction. When such thing arises I have to use Maple or Wolfram alpha, but I was wondering if there was some less computer assisted method to solve this. You mentioned about numerical determination. How does this procedure work?.

Comment: Well some solutions can also be transcendental right?

Comment: For example, you can use the bisection method or newton's method. Google it for more details.

Comment: 'Most' systems of equations cannot be solved by algebraic manipulation. Pretty much anything which can be solved exactly has been covered by high school in principle. After that you are looking at numerical techniques, which is what Maple or Mathematica will be doing.

Comment: @Peter By newton's method. Do you mean [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)?. If so how would it be used in my example?. I'm too novice into this, hence the reason of my question.

Comment: Are the variables integers? Real numbers? Positive? In general there can be infinitely many real solutions to such equations, or none at all. Do you want just one, or all?

Comment: @Servaes I've just updated my question to reflect the nature of my need, which is a numerical method to solve for the unknowns, in this context the variables are real numbers.

Comment: @Paul I use PARI/GP.

Comment: @Peter Interesting but for my less sophisticated requirements Maple is more user friendly.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell PARI/GP is the most user friendly software I am aware of. Of course, Maple is more powerful. But I do not have it, and if I am informed right, it is also not free.

Comment: I was going to compose you an answer using Newton's method but it didn't work for your example because my initial guess of $(x,y)=(1,2)$ was already the exact answer. Could you edit in a more realistic and challenging problem?

Answer (score 1):

The vector version of Newton's method goes like this: suppose you have $n$ equations in $n$ unknowns where the unknowns are $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$ and the equations are
$$f_i(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)=0$$ for $i=1, 2, ..., n$. Then the linear approximation to each equation is
$$\begin{align}f_i(r_1, r_2, \dots, r_n)&=f_i((r_1-x_1)+x_1,(r_1-x_2)+x_2,\dots,(r_n-x_n)+x_n)\\
&\approx f_i(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)+\sum_{j=1}^n(r_j-x_j)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}f_i(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)=0\end{align}$$
Where $x_1=r_1,x_2=r_2,\dots,x_n=r_n$ is the true solution the the system of equations. If we construct the vector $\vec b$ where $b_i=f_i(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$ and the matrix $M$ where $M_{ij}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}f_i(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$ then we can solve for
$$M(\vec x-\vec r)=M\vec y=\vec b$$
Then our next approximation to the solution is $x_j\leftarrow x_j-y_j$
Here is a Matlab example for your posted problem

```
% kinetics.m

x = [0.5;
    2.5];
err = 1;
while abs(err) > 1.0e-12,
    func = [4^x(1)+7^x(2)-53;
        3^x(1)+8^x(2)-67];
    jacobian = [4^x(1)*log(4) 7^x(2)*log(7);
        3^x(1)*log(3) 8^x(2)*log(8)];
    err = jacobian\func;
    fprintf('Error = %e\n', norm(err));
    x = x-err;
end
fprintf('Solution is x = %.16f, y = %.16f\n',x);
```

Output is:

```
Error = 7.745216e-01
Error = 3.381383e+00
Error = 6.486683e-01
Error = 5.944094e-01
Error = 4.931151e-01
Error = 3.146575e-01
Error = 1.086841e-01
Error = 1.055246e-02
Error = 9.001149e-05
Error = 6.479704e-09
Error = 2.232400e-15
Solution is x = 1.0000000000000007, y = 2.0000000000000000
```

It took a while to get going, but once it gets close Newton's method is generally quadratically convergent.

**EDIT**: Let's do one Newton-Raphson iteration by hand. Start with
$$\vec x=\begin{bmatrix}1.1193\\1.9988\end{bmatrix}$$
Evaluate the residual
$$\vec f\left(\vec x\right)=\begin{bmatrix}4^{x_1}+7^{x_2}-53\\
3^{x_1}+8^{x_2}-67\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}4^{1.1193}+7^{1.9988}-53\\
3^{1.1193}+8^{1.9988}-67\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}0.605103\\0.260622\end{bmatrix}$$
And the Jacobian
$$J=\begin{bmatrix}4^{x_1}\ln4&7^{x_2}\ln7\\
3^{x_1}\ln3&8^{x_2}\ln8\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}4^{1.1193}\ln4&7^{1.9988}\ln7\\
3^{1.1198}\ln3&8^{1.9988}\ln8\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}6.542462&95.12721\\
3.75739&132.7526\end{bmatrix}$$
Now we have to solve $J\vec\epsilon=\vec f$ we form the augmented matrix and perform Gaussian elimination.
$$M=\begin{bmatrix}6.542462&95.12721&0.605103\\
3.75739&132.7526&0.260622\end{bmatrix}$$
Divide the first row by $M_{11}=6.542462$
$$M=\begin{bmatrix}1&14.53997&0.092489\\
3.75739&132.7526&0.260622\end{bmatrix}$$
Subtract $M_{21}=3.75739$ times the first row from the second
$$M=\begin{bmatrix}1&14.53997&0.092489\\
0&78.12024&-0.08689\end{bmatrix}$$
Divide the second row by $M_{22}=78.12024$
$$M=\begin{bmatrix}1&14.53997&0.092489\\
0&1&-0.001112308\end{bmatrix}$$
Subtract $M_{12}=14.53997$ times the second row from the first
$$M=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0.108661\\
0&1&-0.001112308\end{bmatrix}$$
So our estimate of the error in our root is the last column
$$\vec\epsilon=\begin{bmatrix}0.108661\\-0.001112308\end{bmatrix}$$
Subtract our error estimate from the current value of $\vec x$ to get our next value of $\vec x$
$$\vec x\leftarrow\vec x-\vec\epsilon=\begin{bmatrix}1.1193\\1.9988\end{bmatrix}-
\begin{bmatrix}0.108661\\-0.001112308\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1.010639\\1.999912\end{bmatrix}$$
And repeat as necessary until the residuals and errors are small enough.

Comment: If I were to try this method "by hand" how would it look the first two equations?. Can you include a solution using Maple too?. I'm more comfortable using it instead of Matlab.

Comment: No possibility of Maple. I did show a Newton-Raphson step by hand.

Comment: Maple isn't capable of doing Newton Raphson?. How did you get $1.1193$ and $1.9988$ in the powers for $4$ and $7$? It looks that there is missing a character between the brackets for $x$ can you check this?. It is not displaying?.

Comment: Not when I don't have Maple! Fixed typos.

Comment: Sorry!. Btw, what made you decide to start with $1.1193$ and $1.9988$?. I understand that the method makes you to begin at some value, but why those weird numbers?.

Comment: That was what I got after $6$ iterations in my Matlab program. It was where the program starting converging pretty fast.

Comment: How long did it took your computer to complete the process?. I'm wondering if I had to resort into a manual computation, the method indicates to select a value and by your steps it seems that I had to fill tons of sheets with matrices. Let's suppose if I had begun with $x_1=0.5$ and $y_1=1$, up from this point how many iterations would had been necessary?.

Comment: From the output I posted you can see that it took $11$ iterations to converge to double precision accuracy from my starting values, With initial values of $$\vec x=\begin{bmatrix}0.5\\1\end{bmatrix}$$ the algorithm actually failed to converge. Even your cell phone could do an iteration in about a microsecond. Filling tons of sheets with matrices is easy if they're spreadsheets:) In fact the hand calculations I posted were actually worked out in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that we are in the real domain with all positive (larger than $1$) real coefficients, for two equations such as
$$a_1^x+b_1^y=c_1 \tag 1$$
$$a_2^x+b_2^y=c_2 \tag 2$$ what you can do is to eliminate $y$ from the first equation
$$a_1^x+b_1^y=c_1 \implies  y=\frac{\log \left(c_1-a_1^x\right)}{\log (b_1)}\tag 3$$

We also know that $x$ has an upper bound which is

$$ x_{max}=\min \left(\frac{\log (c_1)}{\log (a_1)},\frac{\log (c_2)}{\log (a_2)}\right)$$

and this is good piece of information for later.

Plug in $(2)$ to get a function of $x$ only. That is to say that you look for the zero of function
$$f(x)=a_2^x+b_2^{y(x)}-c_2$$ and, now, you can use Newton method for a single variable starting iterations with, say, $x_0=\frac 12 x_{max}$

Let us do it for your example for which the iterates are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 1.43198 \\
 1 & 1.11721 \\
 2 & 1.01019 \\
 3 & 1.00008 \\
 4 & 1.00000
\end{array}
\right)$$ Once you have $x$, go back to $(3)$ to get $y=2$.

Let us make it more difficult with the same coefficients except that $c_1=500$ and $c_2=700$; the iterates are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 2.24145 \\
 1 & 3.33178 \\
 2 & 3.00573 \\
 3 & 2.90125 \\
 4 & 2.89252 \\
 5 & 2.89247
\end{array}
\right)$$ and then $y=3.13363$.

Answer (score 0):

The Maple command `fsolve` will utilize Newton's method for such multivariate problems.

You can supply an initial point, or let it try to find one that converges (the default).

```
restart;

kernelopts(version);

    Maple 2019.2, X86 64 LINUX, Oct 30 2019, Build ID 1430966

eqs := { 4^x + 7^y = 53,
         3^x + 8^y = 67 }:

fsolve( eqs );

           {x = 1.000000000, y = 2.000000000}
```

If you set `infolevel[fsolve]:=2:` then it will also display details of the computation. Set that back to zero (default) to suppress such details.

You can also supply ranges for the variables, etc.

There are additional numeric rootfinding facilities. It often helps to not try and use the symbolic solver `solve` for purely numeric root-finding.